# Extract Month & Year from Date and use in Sumifs

Tags: excel, excel-formula

To convert a date into Month and Year one can use this formula:

```
=TEXT(A4;"MMM-YYYY")
```

(In my local Excel JJJJ stands for YYYY)

I want to use this in a Sumifs formula. To sum all values from a certain month.

=SUMIFS(tb_Expenses[Value];**Text(tb_Expenses[Date];"MMM JJJJ")**;$H$17;tb_Expenses[Category1];G18)

Why is it not possible?

[image]

Comment: You can use your SUMIFS logic, but need to do separate conditions for both `MONTH` and `YEAR`. Also using `TEXT` converts the value in text, so it's no longer a number, like the original value.

Comment: *Why is it not possible?* The second argument for `SUMIFS` must be a Range.  In your formula, it is an array.  If you want to work with arrays, use `SUMPRODUCT`.  If you must use `SUMIFS`, you'll need to add columns with the date part of interest (Month or Month and Year).

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Thank you so much! I tried both your solutions, and they work.